# Inverse function of hypergeometric function, e.g., ${}_{2}F_{1}(1,1;1.2;x)$

Tags: calculus, special-functions, inverse, hypergeometric-function, inverse-function

I want to know whether it is able to express the inverse function of hypergeometric function using some special function.

For instance, the Gauss hypergeometric function $f(x)={}_{2}F_{1}(1,1;1.2;x)$. I want to solve the equation $f(x)=-0.2$. One way to get $x$ is to use Matlab and plots. But I am wondering if it is possible to express the inverse function of hypergeometric functions using some special functions (E.g., [the Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) can be used to express the inverse function of $z\cdot e^{z}$).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can atleast find the power series using the [Lagrange inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem)

Comment: As far as i know, no special function has been defined as standard function for the inverse of hypergeometric function. As you know, one use numerical calculus. Also approximates, for example : http://www.epixanalytics.com/modelassist/CrystalBall/Model_Assist.htm#Distributions/Approximations/Approximations_to_the_Inverse_Hypergeometric_distribution.htm

Comment: @JJacquelin . JJacquelin, thanks for the new knowledge :). the approximation seems quite tight.

Comment: Hi @Vic . The link seems to be broken. Could you please share the approximation? Thanks!

Comment: @sefi hi, I did not save the link, but I think it is the same content as in this page: https://modelassist.epixanalytics.com/display/EA/Approximations+to+the+Inverse+Hypergeometric+distribution

Comment: If a representation of the hypergeometric function as composition of functions does exist, the inverse is the composition of the inverses of these functions in the opposite order.

Comment: $\,_2\text F_1(1,1;1.2;z)=\frac{\text B_z\left(\frac15,\frac45\right)}{5(1-z)^\frac45\sqrt[5]z}$ from [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/03/0006/) and the “invhypergeo function” exists on the Casio calculator, but it’s domain and range are discrete, so it has limited use